# Storybook issue - Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

## Some Relevant Context (I think)

I've worked on many projects that use what I believe are called "barrel dependencies" - a single file that exports a bunch of components for easy importing which looks like this:

```js
// src/components/flexibleBlocks/index.js
export { default as Embed } from './Embed/Embed';
export { default as Image } from './Image/Image';
export { default as Text } from './Text/Text';
export { default as Video } from './Video/Video';
```

It means instead of writing:

```js
import Embed from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks/Embed/Embed';
import Image from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks/Image/Image';
import Text from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks/Text/Text';
import Video from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks/Video/Video';
```

I can instead just do:

```js
import { Embed, Image, Text, Video } from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks';
```

All well and good, works fine, no issues.

## My App Structure

My apps and sites are often displaying content generated in a CMS, where the structure of a page is defined by the content editor, and cannot be hard-coded.

I use the following component to loop through the content:

```js
// src/components/resolvers/FlexibleContentLoop.js
import { FlexibleContentResolver } from 'src/components/resolvers';

const FlexibleContentLoop = ({ flexible_content }) => {
  if (flexible_content) {
    return (
      <>
        {flexible_content.map((props, i) => (
          <FlexibleContentResolver
            key={i}
            {...props}
          />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default FlexibleContentLoop;
```

And the following to render the correct component for each entry in the previous loop:

```js
// src/components/resolvers/FlexibleContentResolver.js
import * as blocks from 'src/components/flexibleBlocks';
import { Missing } from 'src/components/partials';

const FlexibleContentResolver = (props) => {
  const { componentName } = props;
  let Component;
  if (componentName in blocks) {
    Component = blocks[componentName];
    return <Component {...props} />;
  } else {
    return <Missing>Missing block: {componentName}</Missing>;
  }
};

export default FlexibleContentResolver;
```

It seems like an elegant solution to flexible CMS content, and I've used this for years with tools such as Create React App, Next.js, Gatsby, etc. without any issues.

## The Problem:

Storybook doesn't seem to like this. I think it boils down to circular dependencies.

I have my components setup so that you can nest one component loop inside another, which looks like this:

```js
// src/components/flexibleBlocks/DynamicBlock/DynamicBlock.js
import { FlexibleContentLoop } from 'src/components/resolvers';

const DynamicBlock = ({ layouts }) => {
  return (
    <div>{layouts && <FlexibleContentLoop flexible_content={layouts} content_type="layout" />}</div>
  );
};

export default DynamicBlock;
```

I can see why it would be a circular dependency, but it works, and allowing a component to be nested inside itself is a valid pattern.

In some cases I'm seeing this error:

```
  ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization
  at Module.default (http://localhost:6006/src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:113:42)
  at Module.AgeScreen (http://localhost:6006/src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:773:111)
  at registerExportsForReactRefresh (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:796:36)
  at Object.executeRuntime (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:828:3)
  at $ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ (http://localhost:6006/src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:806:34)
  at ./src/components/flexibleBlocks/index.js (http://localhost:6006/src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:819:2)
  at options.factory (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:642:31)
  at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
  at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:299:21)
  at ./src/components/resolvers/FlexibleContentResolver.js (http://localhost:6006/src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:2594:87)
```

And in others this error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
Call Stack
 Module.FlexibleContentResolver
  src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:2808:129
 undefined
  src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:2519:182
 FlexibleContentLoop
  src_components_resolvers_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:2519:34
 renderWithHooks
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:58411:18
 mountIndeterminateComponent
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:62175:13
 beginWork
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:63688:16
 HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:46270:14
 Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:46319:16
 invokeGuardedCallback
  vendors-node_modules_pmmmwh_react-refresh-webpack-plugin_client_ErrorOverlayEntry_js-node_mod-dafa79.iframe.bundle.js:46383:31
```

Is there a workaround to get storybook working with my flexible block components?

I don't think there's an alternative solution for my use case of CMS-driven nested flexible blocks.

Given that every other React tool I've used works fine with this pattern, I'm hoping there's a way to get Storybook working too.

Thanks for any help.